# How to use recursion while rewriting JSON.stringify and return different value if a function is inside or outside an array?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, stringify

I need to rewrite a JSON.stringify function with recursion.
Functions, symbols, and undefined need to be omitted if found inside an object or return null if inside arrays. 
But if the function is the only argument passed (not inside an array nor an object) they must return undefined.

I check for primitive and functions individually first, then if the argument passed is an array I recursively check again against the element inside the array.

I need a way that when the recursion occurs, it also checks if the function is inside the array then returns null, but if it is a stand-alone, it returns undefined. 
My code:

```
var stringifyJSON = function (obj) {
  var arrOfKeyVals = [],
    arrVals = [],
    objKeys = [];
  /*********CHECK FOR PRIMITIVE TYPES**********/
  if (typeof obj === 'number' || typeof obj === 'boolean' || obj === null)
    // coerce the value to become a string
    return '' + obj;
  else if (typeof obj === 'string')
    return '"' + obj + '"';
  else if (typeof obj === 'function') {
    return undefined;
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {

    obj.forEach(function (el) {
      arrVals.push(stringifyJSON(el));
    });
    return '[' + arrVals + ']';
  }
}
```

Comment: Just put a check between `arrVals.push(stringifyJSON(el))` whether the recursive call did return `undefined` or not.

Comment: Btw, you'll need to properly escape strings, not just put quotes on them.

Comment: Similar to Bergi, I would pass a second argument to stringifyJSON 'parentIsArray'. Then inside the function condition check you can return null if parentIsArray. I notices you are not checking if obj is an object after checking if it's an array. Also did you consider doing the same as function with Map data?